# Livecode - How to use keyDown?

Tags: livecode

I've been searching for a long time now and I wanted to know,
How can I code that things will happens when I press on a specific key, (e.g. W).
I found many threads that help in this section with general keys like the delete key or the spacebar and some keyDown theKey, but how do I define "theKey"?
Please help,
FESFEW

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking.. Your current title is a meaningless repetition of the tag information plus "keyDown", which conveys no information. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem, and your current title is useless in that regard. For more information, see [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite for a LiveCode user, the title KeyDown is enough to understand what this is about. An experienced LiveCode user will even be able to give the answer without reading the question.

Comment: @Mark: The comment you responded to was made 3 days ago, and the poster edited the title 2 days ago. IOW, you're about 2 days late, commenting after the poster had edited the title. You should look at dates before chastising someone. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I just waited a day before responding. Still think "LiveCode - Keydown" is sufficient for an experienced LiveCode user.

Comment: @Mark: LiveCode in the title is redundant tag information that shouldn't be in the title at all, which would leave the single word *Keydown*, which clearly is a meaningless title for a post. People asking questions here should be clear and descriptive about the problem they're having. See [ask] to see what the guidelines say about expected quality, or the [help] pages. SO has quality standards for a reason, and new users should be educated about them if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the alphanumeric keys you can use as follows:

```
on keyDown thekey
   switch thekey
      case "w"
         answer "w key pressed"
         break
      default
         pass keyDown
   end switch
end keyDown
```

KeyDown is an event that will be generated each time the user presses a keyboard symbol (not the function keys), the thekey parameter will contain the symbol of the pressed key.

On the other hand, if you want to differentiate capital letters you must set the CaseSensitive property to TRUE

```
set the caseSensitive to true
```

The rawKeyDown property works similarly, but instead of coming in the parameter, the symbol of the pressed key what you will get will be the code of the pressed key including the function keys like shift, F# etc.

```
on rawKeyDown theKeyCode
   switch theKeyCode
      case 32
         answer "SPACE KEY"
         break
      case 119
         answer "w key pressed"
         break
      default
         pass rawKeyDown
   end switch
end rawKeyDown
```

Constants will be very useful to help make your code more readable, adding constants to previous code will look like this (note that the uppercase keys have codes other than the lowercase ):

```
constant kSpaceKey = 32
constant kwKey = 119
constant kWUpperKey = 87

on rawKeyDown theKeyCode
       switch theKeyCode
          case kSpaceKey 
             answer "SPACE KEY"
             break
          case kwKey 
             answer "w key pressed"
             break
          case kwKey 
             answer "w key pressed"
             break
          case kWUpperKey 
             answer "upper W key pressed"
             break
          default
             pass rawKeyDown
       end switch
    end rawKeyDown
```

You can also use this script in the card script to show the code of the key you press:

```
  on rawKeyDown theKeyCode
       put theKeyCode
  end rawKeyDown
```

> Always remember to pass rawKeyDown, rawKeyUp,KeyDown and KeyUp events if you
> want to allow them to continue normal message flow

Comment: Thank you so much, but, in the rawKeyDown, how do I know which case number do I need?